# Display data of class from list in c#

Tags: c#

I was trying to display data of class from list in C#.

Here is my class definition:

```
    class Vehicle
    {
        public string brand;
        public string model;
    }

    class Car : Vehicle
    {
        double trunk_capacity;            
        int doors_number;
        int vmax;
    }
```

Here is my code in which i'm adding car element:

```
    public static void AddCar(List<object> avaliable_cars)
    {
        int x = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Adding new car:");
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Car");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Sport Car");
        Console.WriteLine("3 - Truck");

        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (x)
        {
            case 1: 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding new Car.");

                avaliable_cars.Add(new Car());
                Console.WriteLine("Brand");
                string brand_tmp = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Model");
                string model_tmp = Console.ReadLine();
                avaliable_cars.Add(new Car()
                {
                    brand = brand_tmp,
                    model = model_tmp
                });

            } break;
        }

   }
```

I don't have idea how can i display data from this list.

I was trying to do this

```
foreach (object car in avaliable_cars)
{
  Console.WriteLine(car);
}
```

I doesn't works. Also i want to access one element at one time - for example i want to display brand of first car on the list. How can i do this?

PS Im beginner in C#, so im sorry for any stupid elements in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way would be using generics. You could specialize your method AddCar like this:

```
static void AddCar<T>(List<T> avaliable_cars) 
       where T : Car ,new()
    {
        int x = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Adding new car:");
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Car");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Sport Car");
        Console.WriteLine("3 - Truck");

        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (x)
        {
            case 1: 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding new Car.");

                avaliable_cars.Add(new T());
                Console.WriteLine("Brand");
                string brand_tmp = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Model");
                string model_tmp = Console.ReadLine();
                avaliable_cars.Add(new T()
                {
                    brand = brand_tmp,
                    model = model_tmp
                });

            } break;
        }

   }
```

And to print your data you can simply use T instead of object:

```
foreach (T car in avaliable_cars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(car);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

One clean way of doing this is to override ToString()

```
class Vehicle
{
    public string brand;
    public string model;
    public override ToString()
    {
        return "Brand: " + brand + ", Model: " + model;
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    double trunk_capacity;            
    int doors_number;
    int vmax;
    public override ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() +
           "trunk_capacity: " + trunk_capacity; // etc.
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use

```
Console.WriteLine(car);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need cast the object car to the type Car or Vehicle and then print.

```
foreach (object car in avaliable_cars)
{
  Console.WriteLine(((Vehicle)car).brand);
}
```

Comment: Sure, but that will fail for any other subclass of Vehicle, or for an instance of Vehicle itself.  The code is fragile.

Comment: Agreed using the base class is better in this case, your answer is probably the way to go though.

Comment: I don't think you  need to cast car to vehicle

Comment: You don't need to but you can as Car inherits brand from Vehicle and since the List contains objects it is safer to cast as Vehicle over Car but either would work.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use String.Join or foreach.

```
       List<string> numbers = new List<string>
                    { "One", "Two", "Three","Four","Five"};

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", numbers));


List<string> strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

strings.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```